# AngularJS - Shared service object being deleted incorrectly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, service, controller

When I trigger `deleteQuestion()` a second time 2 `questions` get deleted. Any idea? Let me know if you need to see more of my code.

**controller.js**

```
crtPromoCtrl.controller('surveyCtrl', ['$scope', 'surveySrv', function($scope, surveySrv)
{
    $scope.questions = surveySrv.getQuestions();

    $scope.editQuestion = function(index)
    {
        surveySrv.setEditQuestion(index);
    };

    $scope.deleteQuestion = function(index)
    {
        $(document).off('click', '#confirmationModal #confirm');
        $('#confirmationModal').modal('show');

        $(document).on('click', '#confirmationModal #confirm', function()
        {
            surveySrv.deleteQuestion(index);

            $scope.$apply();
        });
    };
}]);
```

**service.js**

```
crtPromoSrv.service('surveySrv', function()
{
    var questions = [];
    var editQuestion;

    this.getQuestions = function()
    {
        return questions;
    };

    this.addQuestion = function(question)
    {
        questions.push(question);
    };

    this.setEditQuestion = function(index)
    {
        editQuestion = questions[index];
    };

    this.getEditQuestion = function()
    {
        return editQuestion;
    };

    this.clearEditQuestion = function()
    {
        editQuestion = undefined;
    };

    this.deleteQuestion = function(index)
    {
        questions.splice(index, 1);
        console.log(questions);
    };
});
```

EDIT: I'm thinking it's an event propagation thing, since when I have 5 q's it deletes #2 and #3 when I delete #2.

EDIT: Fixed, see controller.js code.

Comment: Never (ever) do DOM manipulation in a controller. This is rule #1 doing Angular when attempting to build modular code with any intent to test it. The controller should be removing the items from the backing array. Manipulation of the DOM is the intention of a directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are adding the `'click'` function to your `#confirmationModal #confirm` button multiple times. The first time `$scope.deleteQuestion` is called, it adds the function. The second time you call it, it adds it *again* so when it is clicked, the function is called twice.

A simple fix would be to unbind the `'click'` event *before* adding it again. Something like this: `$('#confirmationModal #confirm').off('click');`

The **better** solution here is to not use jQuery at all for these event bindings. Using a simple Angular modal directive (like the one provided in the Angular-UI library, for instance) would be the correct way to do this. Then you can just have an `ng-click` on the button and never have this problem.

Comment: Tried this and unbind in the other answer with no luck. If it matters, it seems to be only be triggering a maximum of 2 times, in other words, It doesn't trigger it 3 times the 3rd time I click on it and so on.

Comment: I would recommend changing it to do it the Angular way, like I mentioned. You could use the Angular-UI Modal directive [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). Or if you want something already done for "confirm", you could use something like [this](http://schlogen.github.io/angular-confirm/)

Comment: I got it working by putting the `off` before the `on` instead of the other way around. This will be a momentary fix as I plan to do it the "Angular" way soon. Thanks!